# Is it possible to use Android preference management inside an activity without inherit it from PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences

I want to build my custom preference activity without inherit it from PreferenceActivity, but **I want to keep the standard xml Android preference management**. Is it possible?

Something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends MyCustomActivity {

...
<<get preferences>>
<<manage click events>>
...

}
```

`MyCustomActivity` does not extends any PreferenceActivity.

**I don't want to build my UI to edit preference, I want to use the standard Android UI!**

Comment: yes it is possible manually, add and update preference values using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Comment: Ok, but I lose the standard Xml management. I need to "do it myself"!

Comment: its actually not much, design your 1)UI, 2)in OnStart populate default or previously stored values from XML to UI, 3)in OnStop update the sharedPreference again

Comment: I refined my question: I want to use the standard Android preference UI editing.